# Rows and columns with Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, row, multiple-columns

I am trying to create this webpage:
https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/shutterbugg/index.html

The first two parts of the section work fine, displaying the image next to the picture. However the third part of the section does not display anything. The end tags of two of my div are displayed as white instead of red.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="main">
      <div class="container">
        <h2>Heading</h2>
        <p>Paragraph Text</p>
        <a class="btn" href="#">Download Shutterbug</a>

      </div>
    </div>

   <div class="section">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6">
          <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/shutterbugg/share.png">
        </div>   
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <h2>Heading</h2>
          <p>Paragraph</p>
        </div>
        </div>   

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/shutterbugg/explore.png">
           </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <h2>Heading</h2>
            <p> Text Text Text Text Text </p>
          </div>  
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/shutterbugg/save.png">
          </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <h2>Heading<h3>
            <p>Text Text Text</p>
            </div>
            </div>     
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have closing div's that's not needed.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="section">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/shutterbugg/share.png">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <h2>Heading</h2>
        <p>Paragraph</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/shutterbugg/explore.png">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <h2>Heading</h2>
        <p>Text Text Text Text Text</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/shutterbugg/save.png">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <h2>Heading<h3>
            <p>Text Text Text</p>
      <div>   
    </div>
```

Comment: What does the script do you added at the end?

Comment: Thanks, the body and html element at the bottom of the page have turned white from their original red. However the code still runs.

Comment: Yip. Browsers are more forgiving these days.